# Stack Snippets messing with JS?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

[I've noticed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20986392#20986392) that my Red vs. Blue Sandbox controller snippet [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots-sandbox) has stopped working (at least in Chrome).

This is incredibly strange because the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CalvinsHobbies/utzjow0w/#base) that is exactly identical is working fine. More importantly, if you go to the edit mode for the meta question, the snippet works fine when you click *Run code snippet* in the render preview, or if you click *edit the above snippet* → *Run*.

The error that the browser gives is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

this makes perfect sense when you look at the JavaScript causing it:

```
var battle, redTeam, blueTeam, interval

1385d3a1-d76e-4049-926f-d58c6ff78ba5('#showCircles')
    loadEntries()
})
```

I have no idea where the `1385d3a1-d76e-4049-926f-d58c6ff78ba5` came from. The code should look something like this:

```
var battle, redTeam, blueTeam, interval

$(document).ready(function() {
    ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d')
    moveCounter = $('#moveCounter')
    showNames = $('#showNames')
    showCircles = $('#showCircles')
    loadEntries()
})
```

The edit page has the correct code but the real question doesn't.

I'm guessing it has something to do with jQuery or MathJax because of the `$` involved.

Interestingly, the [official question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots) snippet works fine. The code there is minified though so this may not be that surprising.

Any clue what's going on?

(Not sure but a similar error may be happening [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48589/generate-mathjax-for-the-golden-ratio-continued-fraction?noredirect=1#comment114553_48589).)

Comment: In case it helps, I can reproduce this problem (even the odd hash-looking thing is identical)

Comment: Definitely a MathJax-related problem (I've seen a similar strange effect on CR). Looking into it...

Comment: This is definitely what broke my snippet.

Answer (score 9):

This is a MathJax-related issue. Here are some very short snippets that reproduce the bug, which appears to occur whenever multiple dollar signs are placed in a single code block:

```
$foo
$bar
$baz
```

and

```
$
foo
bar
baz
$
```

Note that the [original source of this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/ad993d34-af26-4d2e-9866-8df1f2593a81/view-source) does not include any extra indentation, yet the rendered HTML does show it.

According to [a comment by @m0sa, Stack Exchange developer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5063/mathjax-breaks-my-indentation#comment10721_5063):

> I looked into it, turned out to be a deep rabbit hole requiring at major refactoring of MarkdownSharp (we'd need to make the pipeline extensible, so we could inject stuff before DoCodeBlocks in RunBlockGamut - currently all the processing happens before we ever hit MarkdownSharp, but we'd need to leverage it's block processing)

So, it's unlikely that this will be fixed any time soon (ugh).

Unfortunately, the answer is just "use `jQuery` or some other alias in your code instead of `$`" until this is fixed.

Comment: Now I'm not so happy we got MathJax. I think bug-free stack snippets are much more important for PPCG. :(

Comment: I was actually going to report this as a bug for code block rendering...

Comment: And I don't get how it can render correctly in the edit preview but not in the actual question. You'd think it'd be the exact same procedure for rendering both of them.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies It's not. Client-side for preview, server-side for actual post.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies It doesn't. Try editing this answer.

Comment: I see. @MartinBüttner The JS in the RvB Sandbox was rendered correctly in the edit preview (there was no hash thing).

Comment: Are the developers aware that dollar signs [break the search](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=perl+nothing) as well?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, Doorknob, there is a similar issue on Music stackexchange and there is a very simple workaround. See my answer and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the meta only, I have edited the MathJax delimiter to use `\\(` and `\\)`. Let me know if this allows your snippets to work better!

Testing alternative MathJax invocation syntax: \(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\)

Display mode still works:

\[\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\]

Another test from Martin:

```
abc$
    $def
$$ab
    de$$
\(ab
de\)
\[ab
de\]
```

Comment: I tried using `$` again instead of `jQuery` in my meta snippet but the same exact issue (strangely?) still occurred.

Comment: On your test from Martin, was it supposed to be formatted as code?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been fixed, it's not showing up in the edit box

```
$foo
        $bar
$baz
```

(no, it's not fixed, `$bar` has additional indentation than what I saw in the edit!)

There is a similar issue on Music Stack exchange, where unwanted guitar chords pop up. The workaround is to use `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags around content you don't want mangled. This also means you don't need to include 4 leading spaces in front of your code.

(Yes, works!)

```
$foo
    $bar
$baz
```

(Please click the edit button to see exactly what I have done.)

Comment: Having to escape `&`, `<`, and other HTML characters isn't fun... nor is the lack of syntax highlighting. (Not to mention the potential to break several of the Stack Snippets that we commonly use.)