# Can we have MathJax back (part II)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, latex

More than a month ago, we've reached a consensus: [We want MathJax back](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14577/can-we-have-mathjax-back). The reasons why it was turned off in 2015 no longer seem to apply, and details about why MathJax is needed on this site are detailed in the linked post. After a while, I [asked a Community Manager](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=42691274#42691274) about what we shall do next, but they were probably busy with other things (such as the election that was just about to start), so I didn't get my question answered.

So, what should we do to have MathJax re-enabled? Can we please have it back?

Comment: I have contacted a CM about this. I'm not sure how long it will take, but they are aware of it and working on it.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Great, thank you! I'm going to keep this meta post, though.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea until we get an official response.

Comment: [I got a better response over here, by the way.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=42697046#42697046)

Comment: I assume you all are interested in a different delimiter? We can go with `\$`, perhaps. A good next step would be to search existing content to see how many posts would break.

Comment: part III post when?

Comment: @JonEricson: It's two posts that would break, see [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44749509#44749509) for more information.

Comment: What's the current status with this?

Comment: @Anush The community managers know about this but there doesn't seem to be any progress in solving the MathJax issue yet. We're still waiting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### MathJax has been re-enabled for PPCG

`\$` is the inline delimiter.

Let us know if there are any problems. We're aware that search is a little bit funky:

[image: funky search]

Comment: [Search](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8808/1402) and [diffs](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8884/1402) are "a little bit funky" on *all* stacks with MathJax enabled.

Comment: Woohoo!  This is great.

Answer (score 2):

\$Test\$

$$Test$$

\$\LaTeX\$