# Why does Community have an answer here?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, meta, users

[Community](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) looks to be [very buggy today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed). However, this appears to be specific to this site - I've been unable to repro this on other sites or their metas.

It appears as though [Community has an answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=answers) on our meta: [Do we really want LaTeX/MathJax (right now)?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/do-we-really-want-latex-mathjax-right-now/5057#5057). I've checked a few other metas on the network, and I can't find any other instance of Community posting answers, aside from some [automated stuff](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/936/48930).

Additionally, Community appears to also go by the name [anon](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5057/revisions) in the revision history of this answer.

This appears to be very weird behaviour by Community, as I'm unable to find any other examples in a brief search of other sites, and it doesn't appear to be any of the [listed behaviours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/355458) for Community

What's going on here?

Comment: My *guess* is that the original owner requested to disown the answer, and it got moved to community.

Comment: @WheatWizard I considered that, but the revision history of the answer shows that it was *created* by Community, whereas I think a disassociation leaves the original OP but blanks their name out to "anon"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was dissociated from the original owner and assigned to Community. Dissociation completely assigns the new assignee (in this case, Community) as the owner of the post, so they will also appear as the one who created the post.