# Arbitrary Stack Snippet Loader

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

The Stack Snippet below loads the first Stack Snippet in the Stack Exchange post defined by `site`, `postID`, and `isAnswer`. (Inspired by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257145/are-stack-snippets-a-good-enough-reason-to-increase-the-30k-post-limit#comment838813_257145) and [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21826346#21826346).)

It assumes there is only one Stack Snippet in the post and may load the wrong code if there is more than one.

- One possible application is to have this point to a generalized leaderboard Snippet. So any changes/fixes to the leaderboard Snippet are reflected in all the Snippets that point to it. [Optimizer has done this.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5314/26997)
- Another application is to point it to a [very long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257145/266052) Snippet that wouldn't fit in the post otherwise.

### A golfed version with copyable raw markdown is available [below](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5312/26997).

This ungolfed Snippet loads from [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5311/26997).

```js
site = 'meta.codegolf'
postID = 5311
isAnswer = true

jQuery(function() {
 var url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/'
 if (isAnswer)
  url += 'answers/' + postID + '?order=asc&sort=creation&site=' + site + '&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD'
 else
  url += 'questions/' + postID + '?order=asc&sort=creation&site=' + site + '&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)'
 jQuery.get(url, function(b) {
   function d(s) { return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text() }
   function r(l) { return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-' + l + '\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>') }
   b = b.items[0].body
   var js = r('js').exec(b), css = r('css').exec(b), html = r('html').exec(b)
   if (css !== null)
    jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(css[1])))
   if (html !== null)
    jQuery('body').append(d(html[1]))
   if (js !== null)
    jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(js[1])))
  }
 )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(I use `jQuery` instead of `$` to hopefully avoid [this issue](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/stack-snippets-messing-with-js).)

Comment: Why is this so complicated when you could just link to the script directly using `<script src='...'></script>` in the HTML section?

Comment: @Doorknob Can you show me how? I'd assumed the `src` had to be a plain js file, so just linking to an answer wouldn't help.

Comment: You can link to the plaintext of a revision [like so](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/94046da6-2b31-420b-bdf3-03e5450450f2/view-source) (it's in the list of revisions, under the "source" link).

Comment: @Doorknob Alright, that gives the js, but to have the css and html you'd  need other revisions or answers, or have to store it as a string in the js, both of which are way less manageable. The snippet in the pointed-to post should be runnable and easy to update.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thought you were only concerned with JS here.

Comment: @Doorknob Initially I was, but turning into a full fledged snippet cloner seemed the most useful. (It's still really nice to know you can link to post plaintext. :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Copyable Version

Copy this exact raw markdown into the post where you want to use the Arbitrary Stack Snippet Loader. Adjust `site`, `postID`, and `isAnswer` in the first `<script>` tag on the second line as necessary.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false --><!-- language: lang-html -->
<script>site = 'codegolf'; postID = 50690; isAnswer = false</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script><!-- end snippet -->
```

#### It should render like this:

```html
<script>site = 'codegolf'; postID = 50690; isAnswer = false</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Test Snippet

```js
jQuery('body').append('Data: ' + site + ', ' + postID + ', ' + isAnswer)
alert('Success!')
```

```css
h3 { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Test HTML</h3>
```