# Cops and robbers not yet cracked answers Stack Snippet

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

You can load this Snippet using the [Arbitrary Stack Snippet Loader](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5312/25180), with the following parameters:

> site = 'meta.codegolf';
>   postID = 5686;
>   isAnswer = false;
>   QUESTION_ID = ;

QUESTION_ID is for the question that the answers could be cracked (the cops thread), **NOT** for the question where the answers are cracking other answers. It doesn't matter where do you put the Snippet.

It requires the comment to contain a link with "cracked" (case insensitive) in the link text, so it wouldn't be a problem if they talk about cracking without posting a real crack, OR there is a "cracked" in the first line of the answer, since we couldn't edit the comment if it wasn't in the right format. And it apparently has more rules that I have forgotten.

```js
var safe_list=[];
var uncracked_list=[];
var n=0;
var bycreation=function(x,y){return (x[0][0]<y[0][0])-(x[0][0]>y[0][0]);};
var bylength=function(x,y){return (x[0][1]>y[0][1])-(x[0][1]<y[0][1]);};
function u(l,o){
  jQuery(l[1]).empty();
  l[0].sort(o);
  for(var i=0;i<l[0].length;i++)
    l[0][i][1].appendTo(l[1]);
  if(l[0].length==0)
    jQuery('<tr><td colspan="3" class="message">none yet.</td></tr>').appendTo(l[1]);
}
function m(s) {
  if('error_message' in s)
    jQuery('#api_error').text('API Error: '+s.error_message);
}
function g(p) {
  jQuery.getJSON('//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + QUESTION_ID + '/answers?page=' + p + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=!.Fjs-H6J36w0DtV5A_ZMzR7bRqt1e', function(s) {
    m(s);
    s.items.map(function(a) {
      var he = jQuery('<div/>').html(a.body).children().first();
      he.find('strike').text('');
      var h = he.text();
      if (!/cracked/i.test(h) && (typeof a.comments == 'undefined' || a.comments.filter(function(b) {
        var c = jQuery('<div/>').html(b.body);
        return /^cracked/i.test(c.text()) || c.find('a').filter(function() {
          return /cracked/i.test(jQuery(this).text())
        }).length > 0
      }).length == 0)) {
        var m = /^\s*((?:[^,;(\s]|\s+[^-,;(\s])+)\s*(?:[,;(]|\s-).*?([0-9]+)/.exec(h);
        var e = [[n++, m ? parseInt(m[2]) : null],
          jQuery('<tr/>').append(
            jQuery('<td/>').append(
              jQuery('<a/>').text(m ? m[1] : h).attr('href', a.link)),
            jQuery('<td class="score"/>').text(m ? m[2] : '?'),
            jQuery('<td/>').append(
              jQuery('<a/>').text(a.owner.display_name).attr('href', a.owner.link))
          )];
        if(/safe/i.test(h))
          safe_list.push(e);
        else
          uncracked_list.push(e);
      }
    });
    if (s.items.length == 100)
      g(p + 1);
    else {
      var s=[[uncracked_list, '#uncracked'], [safe_list, '#safe']];
      for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
        u(s[i],bylength);
      jQuery('#uncracked_by_length').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],bylength);return false});
      jQuery('#uncracked_by_creation').bind('click',function(){u(s[0],bycreation);return false});
    }
  }).error(function(e){
    m(e.responseJSON);
  });
}
g(1);
```

```css
table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
.score {
  text-align: right;
}
table a {
  display: block;
}
.main {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.main h3,
.main div {
  margin: 5px;
}
.message {
  font-style: italic;
}
#api_error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=7509797c03ea">
<div id="api_error"></div>
<div class="main">
<h3>Uncracked submissions</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th class="score">Length</th>
    <th>User</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="uncracked"></tbody>
</table>
<div>Sort by:
  <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_length">length</a>
  <a href="#" id="uncracked_by_creation">creation</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<h3>Safe submissions</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th class="score">Length</th>
    <th>User</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="safe"></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I really don't understand your code, so how could I order the list from shortest to longest code?

Comment: And by the way, this is great and saved me a huge amount of work :)

Comment: @BetaDecay Changed to sort by length (and ungolfed the code). It was firstly used in [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51068/25180).

Comment: Whoa, this is awesome. Excellent work, Jimmy!

Answer (score 1):

#### Example usage

```html
<script>site = 'meta.codegolf'; postID = 5686; isAnswer = false; QUESTION_ID = 40932;</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```